# what's difference of two ways of creating NSFetchRequest

Tags: ios, core-data, nsfetchrequest

way1:

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Event" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
```

way2:

```
NSFetchRequest* fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Event"];
```

In way1, one Managed Object Context is required but not in way2.
Can anybody clarify the difference between these two?  Especially on the performance.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is that in your second option the context used to resolve the supplied entity string to the actual entity is acquired when the request is executed in the context `executeFetchRequest:error:` while in your first option you resolve the entity yourself.

if you use multiple stores that share the same model, you should set the entity of the request each time you execute the fetch (if you use a different store) so that you get the results you requested.